# Can I change the default set of excludeFolders for generated IML for an imported grails project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, grails, iml

When importing a grails project, it will automatically build an iml file for it. However, I always end up marking web-app folder as excluded. I have to do this with every imported project. I wanted to put IML into VCS, however, since it's generated and it contains local environment-specific stuff, we can't really push it to VCS.

Is there a way to somehow modify the default contents of a generated IML file?

The set is

```
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/work/resources" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/work/scriptCache" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/web-app" />                   // THIS ONE IS MISSING
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/work/stubs" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/work/tomcat" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/work/plugin-classes" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/work/plugin-build-classes" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/work/plugin-provided-classes" />
```

It seems pretty generic, probably generated identically for imported maven projects. Is it possible for me to modify the defaults for new imported maven projects somehow?

Comment: "Is it possible for me to modify the defaults for new imported maven projects somehow?" - Is this a Grails 2 project that is configured to build with Maven?

Comment: "I wanted to put IML into VCS" - What are the goals you are satisfying by including the IML in VCS?

Comment: > Grails 2, yes. 
> Goal — folder exclusion would be in VCS — everyone would have it excluded and checking out the project and opening in IDEa would result in the folder being excluded by default.

Comment: "everyone would have it excluded" - I see.  That makes more sense.  When you said "I wanted to put IML into VCS" I thought you meant the opposite.  Makes sense!